# Can't remove all objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

For some reason, I keep getting this error when I run my app:

`[__NSArrayI removeAllObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I set up the NSMutableArray in .m like this:

```
@implementation ChooseViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *trackName;
}
```

And populate it like this:

```
trackName = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackName"];
```

But when I run this code, it gives me the error:

```
[trackName removeAllObjects];
```

Everything else works fine and the data in trackName works. It's just messing up when I run this code. The only other time trackName array is mentioned is for table view count:

`return [trackName count];`

Do you see anything wrong? I believe the problem is that somewhere it thinks it's an NSArray, but none of them are.

Comment: valueforkeypath is returning non mutable array so before assigning to trackName convert into mutable using mutableCopy function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mutable problem.

```
trackName = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackName"];
```

This line will result into immutable array to trackName. Change to this:

```
trackName = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackName"] mutableCopy];
```

Now, `trackName` is mutable so that you can call.

```
[trackName removeAllObjects];
```