# Crash while removing values from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

This is my code :

```
SHARED_MGR.aryToDoList.removeAllObjects()
```

It is an MutableArray with data model objects . Somehow I am getting crash as :

> Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray removeAllObjects]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x618000231720

I have type checked if the array is of type `NSArray` but it returns **false** as a result, doing the same with `NSMutableArray` return true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980036/cant-remove-all-objects-in-nsmutablearray

Comment: Checked it already , not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below line of code for this

```
SHARED_MGR.aryToDoList = []
```

Comment: I am getting the same error while replacing objects in the same error through replaceObject(at: index, with : obj) method, do you have any workaround for it?

Comment: Your array is not having that length may be and you are trying to replace  on that index

Comment: If the above answer helped you for previous question please accept this

Comment: Had to wait 8 mins for it :D